# string.find() returns true when ==-1 is used but false when <0 is used

Tags: c++, string, find

I am trying to find a character within a string but I am getting unexpected results. My understanding is that `string::find(char c)` returns `-1` when it is not found. However, I am getting some unexpected results.

Even though the string does not include an `'8'`, it is still returning `true`.

```
std::string s = "123456799";
if(s.find('8')<0)
    cout << "Not Found" << endl;
else
    cout <<  "Found" << endl;

//Output: Found
```

However, when using `==` instead the code works as expected.

```
std::string s = "123456799";
if(s.find('8')==-1)
    cout << "Not Found" << endl;
else
    cout <<  "Found" << endl;

//Output: Not Found
```

Comment: [Please read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).  Where does it say `std::string_find` returns `-1`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  std::string_find returns  string::npos if not found,  string::npos is 'static const size_t npos = -1;'

Comment: @user3196144 Note the type of `npos` is unsigned; it's initialized with value `-1` doesn't mean it's negative. And note the explanation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), "This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type."

Comment: @user3196144 And note that the OP followed your advice, and now had to ask a question on SO as to why their program fails to work.  Always read the documentation.  If the function returns a value, and that value is named such as `npos`, return `npos`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My understanding is that `string::find(char c)` returns `-1` when it is not found.

It's not accurate. According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find#Return_value):

> Return value
>   Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no
>   such substring is found.

So to be precise, when not found `std::string::find` will return [std::string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos). The point is that the type of `std::string::npos` is `std::string::size_type`, which is an unsigned integer type. Even it's initialized from value of `-1`, it's not `-1`; it's still unsigned. So `s.find('8')<0` will always be `false` because it's not possible to be negative.

Documentation of [std::string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

> ```
> static const size_type npos = -1;
> ```
>
> This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type `size_type`.

So you should use [std::string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) for checking the result, to avoid such kind of confusing.

```
if (s.find('8') == std::string::npos)
    cout << "Not Found" << endl;
else
    cout <<  "Found" << endl;
```

---

`if(s.find('8')==-1)` works fine, because the left-hand operand of [operator==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators) here is unsigned, the right-hand one is signed. According to the rules for [arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions),

> - Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.

So `-1` will be converted to unsigned, which is the value of `std::string::npos` and then all work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`string::find()` returns `size_t`, which is an unsigned int so it can never be negative.