# c++ std::string.find returns unexected result in boolean expression

Tags: c++, string, boolean, posix

I'm trying to search for the presence of '..' in a string that represents a file path on a POSIX system.  I'm using std::string.find(".."), and it seems to be finding the correct index, but is not evaluating correctly in boolean expressions.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  std::string a = "abcd";

  int apos = a.find( ".." );

  bool test1 = a.find( ".." ) >= 0;
  bool test2 = apos >= 0;

  if ( test1 ) {
    printf( "TEST1 FAILED: %ld >= 0!\n", a.find( ".." ) );
  }
  if ( test2 ) {
    printf( "TEST2 FAILED %d >= 0!\n", apos );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
$ ./test 
TEST1 FAILED: -1 >= 0!
$
```

Any ideas why `a.find( ".." )` is not evaluating to -1 in the boolean expressions?

Comment: Enable more compiler warnings. Specifically, you should be interested in `error: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Werror=type-limits]`.

Comment: Because the return type of `std::find` is an unsigned integer, it couldn't be negative. See [string.find() returns true when ==-1 is used but false when <0 is used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40392882/3309790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been asked today.

It's because `find` returns `npos` which is an `unsigned int`, it is initialized using `-1` however it's type is `unsigned int`, so that it is larger than `0`.

You should compare `find`'s result with `npos` not `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool test1 = a.find( ".." ) != std::string::npos;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/